# Java - extract content inside square brackets (ignore nested square brackets)?

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, parsing

I want to extract the string content inside square brackets (**if inside one square brackets contains nested square brackets**, **it should be ignored**).

Example:

```
c[ts[0],99:99,99:99] + 5 - d[ts[1],99:99,99:99, ts[2]] + 5
```

Should return:

```
 match1 = "ts[0],99:99,99:99";
 match2 = "ts[1],99:99,99:99, ts[2]";
```

The code I have so far works only with non-nested square brackets

```
String in = "c[ts[0],99:99,99:99] + 5 - d[ts[1],99:99,99:99, ts[2]] + 5";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(in);

while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}

// print: ts[0, ts[1, 2
```

Comment: In should ignore when there are nested brackets but in `Should return` there are nested brackets of the outer ones? Can you add an example that should not be returned?

Answer (score 1):

I made a function to do it (not with regex, but it works)

```
  for (int i = 0; i < in.length(); i++){
        char c = in.charAt(i);
        String part = String.valueOf(c);
        int numberOfOpenBrackets = 0;
        if (c == '[') {
            part = "";
            numberOfOpenBrackets++;
            for (int j = i + 1; j < in.length(); j++) {
                char d = in.charAt(j);
                if (d == '[') {
                    numberOfOpenBrackets++;
                }
                if (d == ']') {
                    numberOfOpenBrackets--;
                    i = j;
                    if (numberOfOpenBrackets == 0) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                part += d;
            }

            System.out.println(part);
            part = "[" + part + "]";
        }

        result += part;
    }

    // print: ts[0],99:99,99:99
    //        ts[1],99:99,99:99, ts[2]
```

Answer (score 1):

Without regex; just straight java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BracketParser {

    public static List<String> parse(String target) throws Exception {
        List<String> results = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int idx = 0; idx < target.length(); idx++) {
            if (target.charAt(idx) == '[') {
                String result = readResult(target, idx + 1);
                if (result == null) throw new Exception();
                results.add(result);
                idx += result.length() + 1;
            }
        }
        return results;
    }

    private static String readResult(String target, int startIdx) {
        int openBrackets = 0;
        for (int idx = startIdx; idx < target.length(); idx++) {
            char c = target.charAt(idx);
            if (openBrackets == 0 && c == ']')
                return target.substring(startIdx, idx); 
            if (c == '[') openBrackets++;
            if (c == ']') openBrackets--;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(parse("c[ts[0],99:99,99:99] + 5 - d[ts[1],99:99,99:99, ts[2]] + 5"));
    }
}
```

[Complete code on GitHub](https://github.com/marco-ruiz/stackoverflow-qa/tree/master/so-common/src/main/java/so/a56187877)

Answer (score 1):

If the nesting is just one level, you can search for a sequence between the brackets:

- a sequence of:
- either a not a `[`
- or a `[` followed by the shortest sequence to `]`

So

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[([^\\[]|\\[.*?\\])*\\]");
//                             [                   ]
//                              ( not-[ or
//                                        [, shortest sequence to ]
//                                               )* repeatedly
```

The problem being that brackets must be correctly paired: no syntax errors allowed.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to add a right boundary in your expression and `ts` start and swipe everything in between, which might work, maybe similar to [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/WTRcJT/1):

```
(ts.*?)(\]\s+\+)
```

If we have more chars here: `(\s\+)`, you can simply add it with logical ORs in a char list and it would still work.

#### RegEx

If this wasn't your desired expression, you can modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/e3M8hT/1).
[image]

#### RegEx Circuit

You can also visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]