# Regex query in C# to select everything inside square brackets including nested square brackets

Tags: c#, regex

Does anyone know of how I can split a string such as the following:

> [expression one [parameter 1]] do not match [expression two [parameter 3] some other options]

I would like to split the string into the following result:

> expression one [parameter 1]
>   expression two [parameter 3] some other options

I am using c#

[Java - extract content inside square brackets (ignore nested square brackets)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56187237/java-extract-content-inside-square-brackets-ignore-nested-square-brackets)

Comment: I would use loops if I were you, that could be easier to implement.

Comment: Do you have an example string?